IQ tests versus Psychological evaluation
If you have been under psychological evaluation by a psychiatrist who says you have high intelligence, but your IQ test has you at 105, is the test the problem?  The doctor is evaluating creative skills, which which doesn't seem to be present in the test.

Possible duplicate of: Is there a correlation between high IQ and creativity?
